# What is wrong with my simple function-call intel x64 machine code?

Tags: 64-bit, intel, machine-code

Here is my function calling code:

```
(Instructions start at 0x00403000)
6A 28                      (Stack Push 0x28)
EB 0A                      (Jump 10)
40 80 04 25 03 10 40 00 05 (Add 5 to address 0x00401003)
C3                         (Near return)
FF 14 25 04 30 40 00       (Call 0x00403004)
```

This causes my program to blow up instead of calling MessageBoxA later in the code.  Here is the functional code that works but without the function call:

```
(Instructions start at 0x00403000)
6A 28                       (Stack Push 0x28)
EB 0A                       (Jump 10)
40 80 04 25 03 10 40 00 05  (Add 5 to address 0x00401003)
C3                          (Near return)
40 80 04 25 03 10 40 00 05  (Add 5 to address 0x00401003)
```

Here's the code after these snippets:

```
48 B9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   (Copy 0 to 64-register 1) 
48 BA 00 10 40 00 00 00 00 00   (Copy 0x00401000 to 64-register 2)
49 B8 06 10 40 00 00 00 00 00   (Copy 0x00401006 to 64-register 3)
49 B9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   (Copy 0 to 64-register 4) 
FF 14 25 78 20 40 00            (Call MessageBoxA)
48 B9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   (Copy 0 to 64-register 1)
FF 14 25 88 20 40 00            (Call End Process)
```

Comment: The code makes no sense. It doesn't follow the Windows x86 calling conventions, and the `call 0x004030004` calls an unspecified function.

Comment: Hmm I checked the Windows calling conventions, it says I can load up the first four registers as parameters and that's what I do.  The 'call 0x004030004' just specifies to jump to that 'Add 5 to address' function.  Do I need to specify the function in machine-code?  How do I do that?  Like I said the version that doesn't call the function works.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Btw I have global variables first at 0x00401000, my imports at 0x00402000, and then these instructions at 0x00403000

Comment: There's more to the calling convention than just setting up registers. The stack must be set up properly, and you need to declare unwind codes. (And the push of 0x28 does not appear to accomplish anything useful.) Also, you are using a call indirect, but from your comments it sounds like you want a direct call.

Comment: I've been going off this: https://i.imgur.com/LIImg.jpg  The code doesn't work at all without pushing 0x28.  Ok so how do I do a direct call?  Sorry I'm so clueless, there's so little documentation on using machine code directly without assembly...

Comment: Also I'm looking at the calls in the x64 manual and it says the direct calls are invalid in 64-bit mode?

Comment: That diagram doesn't discuss the calling convention. It also lacks an exception directory. Also, direct call is perfectly fine. Opcode `e8`. The `push 0x28` aligns the stack by accident; but you forgot to reserve home space. And the reason there is so little documentation on using machine code directly is that nobody does it. Everybody uses an assembler to do the grunt work. If you really need to work in machine code, you should first have a lot of experience with assembly. Start with assembly, not machine code.